# Refer to a variable without writing its name

Tags: pug

I have a Jade template with passed variables from Express through res.locals. For the sake of simplicity let's say one is named 'foo' and the other is named 'bar', and a method to know which one is passed (they can't be both passed), named 'getVariableName'.

From within my template, I can store the variable name this way:

```
-var name = getVariableName()
```

However, I have no way to get the value of the variable this way. `name` now contains either `"foo"` or `"bar"` but there is no global object I can use to store foo or bar's value, like I would in normal JS: `var val = this[name];` that would return either bar or foo's value.

How can I achieve that in Jade without writing `foo` or `bar` explicitly?

Comment: I've tried `eval(name)` but it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently `eval()` works just fine. No idea why it didn't when I first wrote the question. Problem solved.